# How can I initialize an androidx ViewModel from parcelable data?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, parcelable, android-viewmodel

In my Android app, I pass custom data (UByteArray) from one activity to another using the parcelable interface.

I am using this data inside multiple fragments, so I rewrote the data class to extend [androidx ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) and expose LiveData properties to the fragments. Now the UI updates are a lot nicer, but I think I am using it wrong because I overwrite all ViewModel values inside `onCreate`.

Now my question: What do I need to change to initialize the ViewModel only once?
The following is my current code (abbreviated and renamed for this question):

```kotlin
class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val bData: ViewModelB by viewModels()
  // ...

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    intent.getParcelableExtra<ViewModelB>("id")?.let {
      Log.e(TAG, "Found parceled bData $it")
      // This seems like a very stupid way to do it, is there a better one?
      bData.copyAll(it)
    }
  }
}
```

I saw that it is possible to inject [SavedState](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) into the ViewModelB constructor, but I don't have a saved state until now, and the data needs to be passed only once.

Should I change the initialization of tagData with `by viewModels()` to `= ViewModelB(intent)`?
Or do I need to extend the ViewModelFactory somehow?

Any tip here would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `ViewModel` which implements `Parcelable`, you can get your `ViewModelB` instance directly from the `Intent` extra.

The `Intent` which is used for starting `ActivityB` may not be `!= null` at the time when `ActivityB` is instantiated, but you can use

```
lateinit var bData: ViewModelB
```

Then in `onCreate()`

```
bData = if(intent.hasExtra("id")) intent.getParcelableExtra<ViewModelB>("id") else ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelB::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.
I had hoped I could still make it immutable but this is definitely better than my inital approach.

Comment: Can you change `viewModelProviders.of(this)` to `viewModelProvider(this)` in your answer? `ViewModelProviders.of` is marked as deprecated.

Comment: @marcw - it looks like EpicPandaForce provided the answer you were looking for (with an immutable ViewModelB). If it works for you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw that it is possible to inject SavedState into the ViewModelB constructor, but I don't have a saved state until now, and the data needs to be passed only once.

The official solution would be to provide a `SavedStateHandle` that is initialized with the `defaultArgs` as the `intent.extras` of your Activity.

For that, you need to provide an `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` implementation, OR use `SavedStateViewModelFactory` (in which case you must define the right constructor in order to have it instantiated via reflection).

```
class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val bData: ViewModelB by viewModels {
      SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, this, intent.extras)
  }
  // ...

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    // intent.getParcelableExtra<ViewModelB>("id")?.let {
    //      Log.e(TAG, "Found parceled bData $it")
  }
}
```

Then in your ViewModel

```
@Keep
class ViewModelB(val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
    val uByteData = savedStateHandle.get<UByteArray>("id")
}
```

Or so. The `"id"` key must match the same key as is in the intent extras.